# App and InApp Purchase second rejection

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

App History: I'm trying to send the update of an app that is already in store. This version is the first with In App Purchase code implemented. I have tested app and inapp,all works in sandbox environment. Naturraly i can't test the official environment until the inapp is approved, but i'm sure that the php script i use verify recipit works because i'm still using it with other apps already in store.

First Submit: i have send to review the inapp and the app at the same time,it seems all ok but my app was rejected due the impossibility to purchase the inapp. At the same time my inapp was rejected, and in itunes i have found this:
[image]

In the detail of the inapp:
[image]

Clicking in the Language Detail:[image]

At this point i have searched trought my itunes app settings and i found a setting that regards the language, in "App Information" section the default language is setted to a different language of the inapp. I have changed this setting and now app and inapp have all the same language. I have deleted inapp and i have create another with the same name,identifier ecc. The inapp status is changed to waiting to review, then i have resubmit the same bundle for the app.

Second Submit: My app and my in app was rejected again. The error,the cause of rejection is the same and i have the same behavior in inapp section. The message in resolution center is this:

---

"2.2

We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPhone 5 running iOS 6.0.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, we noticed that an error message is displayed when attempting to purchase the In App AddOn.

Please see the attached screenshot for more information."

---

I think this message is mileading, the error message displayed by my app is an alert that i fire when i receive a SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed or when i can't verify a recipit. All this functions works correctly in sandbox.

What's wrong with my inapp?? 
Anyone have expirienced something similar?

Comment: I'm Also having the same issue. I don't know What to change in language setting. They rejected the app By stating that One or more in-app purchase is in developer Action needed state.

Comment: You may can ask apple review team about the issue.  they will let you know the exact issue. I m waiting for their reply.   Use the Link : http://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewboard/

Comment: how long time ago have you send your question to that link?

Comment: Yesterday only. Just now they Sent me an Email. They need to talk with me in this regard. So they asked me Phone numbers and told that it may take few days for me to get the call from Them. I m waiting ....

Comment: If you'll find a solution after them call, please tell me...

Comment: Yes Sure, Till Now no call .. Still Waiting ...... Also if you get any Help from Any Source Then please Let me know, We both are in same Boat.

Comment: Have you got the solution ? I do have the same issue.

Comment: I also have the same problem, do you have a solution ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by [Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Answer (score 1):

This is the bit that caught my attention:

> i can't verify a **recipit**. All this functions works correctly in **sandbox**

Is it possible that you forgot to change the URL that you are using to verify receipts from the sandbox URL to the live URL?

Comment: In my case the reviewer have not made a success purchase => no receipt, so no url problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem with an app submitted to Apple. 
There is a fallback system that needs to be in place for server side in app purchase validation. 
It is documented in Apple, but VERY well hidden in tech note : 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Here is the way to do it :

"Always verify your receipt first with the production URL; proceed to verify with the sandbox URL if you receive a 21007 status code.
Following this approach ensures that you do not have to switch between URLs while your application is being tested or reviewed in the sandbox or is live in the App Store."