# InApp Purchase app rejection

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, in-app-purchase

I have an issue regarding in app purchase. if user doesn't logged in with test user account then in app purchase is not working and loader is spinning for several minutes.my app is rejected due to this reason.Please suggest me the solution for the same.

my problem is exactly similar to [App and InApp Purchase second rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256752/app-and-inapp-purchase-second-rejection) but i am not getting any solution.

Comment: Are you sure, You are testing the app in sandbox mode? Make sure you test the inAppPurchase in sandbox mode & the store URL is reachable. After this, You need to share some piece of code to check.

Comment: Yes I am testing in sandbox mode. If I remove my credential from device settings and test in-app with test user, then everything is working fine. But when apple tested it, they faced the problem that In-app is not working, may be they are not logged in with test user account.

Comment: Are you using a receipt verification server ?

Comment: By "if user doesn't logged in with test user account" do you mean that the user explicitly cancels Apple's request to sign in with an Apple ID?

Answer (score 0):

If user doesn't enter the test account, then go into `delegate` method which will give you error and insert this code.

```
if (!((error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) && (error.code != SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed))){
    NSLog(@"User Cancelled");
}
```

Using code above, you can hide your spinner and end the transaction.